# MongoDB schema for daily entries

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've been trying to figure out what's the best way to structure my MongoDB database. I'm working on a meteor app that keeps track of daily user data. Currently I have 1 collection that holds all the users data. Each user has their own categories and each category has it's own set of sub categories. All of these can be edited by the user so they are not standard which is why it's a bit confusing.

The was I have it now is show below. However, with this set up it means that I will have a new document in my collection every day, per user, per category, per sub category. This seems pretty insufficient.

```
            Collection.insert({
                  date: today,
                  dateNum: new Date(today),
                  userID: 24329843,
                  category: "Cat1",
                  subcategory: "sub1",
                  entry: {
                      report: false, 
                      pts: 0
                    }
            })
```

I was hoping to have one document per day for all the users and use the data structure to store each user's data separately. But this would require the keys for the categories and subcategories to differ from user to user (each user can edit their own categories and subcategories). Would this be the better schema or is having a ton of smaller documents better?

```
                Collection.insert({
                      date: today,
                      dateNum: new Date(today),
                      userID: 24329843,
                      categories: {
                          cat1: {
                                  sub1: {
                                      entry: {
                                      report: false, 
                                      pts: 0
                                      }
                                 }
                          }
                      }
                   });
```

Comment: after you store the data what kind of queries will you be making?

Comment: I'll need to pull the categories, subcategories of each user and the report and pts of each subcategory.

Comment: so, each `category` will never have itson own `entry`, `report` or `pts`? It will only have a `subcategory` with those proteries?

Comment: Correct. Categories only have subcategories.

Comment: The short answer is 'It depends...'.  I suggest you start reading [Thinking in documents](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/thinking-documents-part-1) and the [MongoDB Data Models documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).